# Having trouble working out an SQL query that will get me the result I want

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table that looks vaguely like this:

```
ReferralId   EpisodeId     DateOfReferral    Hospital
1            1             20/04/2019        1
2            1             21/04/2019        2
3            2             28/04/2019        2
4            2             24/04/2019        3
5            2             24/04/2019        1
6            3             22/04/2019        1
7            3             24/04/2019        4
```

I'm trying to query this table to bring back EpisodeIds that have more than one referral on the same date BUT those two referrals have different hospitals.  So the result for the above table would just be:

```
EpisodeId
2
```

I'm not too bad when it comes to SQL, but I just can't wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want episodes but not the dates or hospitals, then this is one of the rare cases where `select distinct` can be used with `group by`:

```
select distinct EpisodeID
from t
group by EpisodeId, DateOfReferral
having count(distinct Hospital) > 1;
```

Or, you can do this without aggregation:

```
select distinct EpisodeID
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.EpisodeId = t.EpisodeId and
                    t2.DateOfReferral = t.DateOfReferral and
                    t2.Hospital <> t.Hospital
             );
```

This version in particular can take advantage of an index on `(EpisodeId, DateOfReferral, Hospital)`, which might make it faster than a `GROUP BY` approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HAVING with a count distinct for this easily.

Also you really should be using the proper datatypes. Storing dates as strings is a bad idea. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

```
declare @Something table
(
    ReferralId int
    , EpisodeId int
    , DateOfReferral varchar(20)
    , Hospital int
)

insert @Something values
(1, 1, '20/04/2019', 1)
, (2, 1, '21/04/2019', 2)
, (3, 2, '28/04/2019', 2)
, (4, 2, '24/04/2019', 3)
, (5, 2, '24/04/2019', 1)
, (6, 3, '22/04/2019', 1)
, (7, 3, '24/04/2019', 4)

select EpisodeID
from @Something s
group by EpisodeId
    , DateOfReferral
having count(distinct Hospital) > 1
```

Comment: OK, but if an episode appears twice on two different dates, this will return the episode ID twice.

Comment: @GMB it isn't clear to me if they want a row for each date this happens or a single row per EpisodeID. But yes if there are multiple dates with multiple hospitals this will return a row for each of those dates.

Comment: Just a single episodeid. I want to find out which episodes are getting more than one referral at the same time on a given day to more than one hospital.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EpisodeId FROM table
GROUP BY EpisodeId,DateOfReferral
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Hospital)>1
```

(I was typing too slow on my smartphone - just noticed that this is the same as the previous answer, that wasn’t there’s when I started. )